# Require.js 404 - script not loading

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

I am using John Papa's single page app and I have ran into a problem where on my dev server it doesn't download require.js. It's odd because when I debug in localhost it can find the script.

**HTML**

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CCJS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <script>
        // Must be first. IE10 mobile viewport fix
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
            var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
            var mq = "@@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}";
            msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mq));
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
        }
    </script>

    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.11.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/modernizr")
</head>
<body>

    <div id="applicationHost">
        @RenderPage("_splash.cshtml")
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/vendor")
    <script src="/App/durandal/amd/require.js" data-main="App/main"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using scriptbundles as well.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace AgencyUpdate
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            try
            {
                bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
                AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(bundles.IgnoreList);

                bundles.Add(
                    new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/modernizr")
                        .Include("~/scripts/modernizr-{version}.js"));
                bundles.Add(
                  new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
                    .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/knockout-{version}.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/sammy-{version}.min.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/moment.min.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/Q.min.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/breeze.debug.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/toastr.min.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/apps/exeOnEnter.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/custom.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/test.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/knockout.mapping.js")
                    .Include("~/scripts/jquery.storage.js")
                  );

                bundles.Add(
                  new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
                    .Include("~/Content/ie10mobile.css")
                    .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
                    .Include("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css")
                    .Include("~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css")
                    .Include("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css")
                    .Include("~/Content/durandal.css")
                    .Include("~/Content/toastr.css")
                    .Include("~/Content/app.css")
                    .Include("~/Content/styles.css")
                    .Include("~/Content/custom.css")
                  );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }

        public static void AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(IgnoreList ignoreList)
        {
            if (ignoreList == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ignoreList");
            }

            ignoreList.Ignore("*.intellisense.js");
            ignoreList.Ignore("*-vsdoc.js");
            //ignoreList.Ignore("*.debug.js", OptimizationMode.WhenEnabled);
            //ignoreList.Ignore("*.min.js", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);
            //ignoreList.Ignore("*.min.css", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my browser**

[image: Browser]

[image: Solution explorer in vs]

Comment: You should really try `~/App/durandal/amd/require.js` for your script tag declaration.  Your screenshot is showing a 404 on the require.js, so I don't believe you when you say that it's correctly loading.  Check the main app script too.  I also recommend checking out his Hot Towel example -- it should work out of the box.